# Excel - datetime with miliseconds do not display correctly

Tags: excel, decimal, separator

I want to solve this trough native Excel if possible (not trough external script, macros etc.)

Its about making report, copy data (timestamps) from MS SQL to Excel. So I put in my clipboard exactly this content:

```
2014-09-02 13:18:58.683
2014-09-02 13:19:16.440
2014-09-02 14:14:04.110
2014-09-02 15:03:37.607
2014-09-02 18:14:11.193
2014-09-02 18:17:56.343
2014-09-02 18:20:50.687
2014-09-02 18:21:06.180
2014-09-02 19:07:16.117
2014-09-02 21:13:05.113
2014-09-02 21:23:38.450
2014-09-03 06:55:28.533
2014-09-03 06:55:40.057
2014-09-03 07:03:43.480
2014-09-03 07:09:09.877
2014-09-03 07:09:40.670
2014-09-03 07:10:00.313
2014-09-03 07:12:03.843
2014-09-03 07:54:15.187
2014-09-03 07:54:25.007
2014-09-03 07:54:36.093
```

(with windows end lines )

and paste it into Excel.

Problem is, that lines 13, 20, 21 do not display correctly, like the other lines. There may be several reasons:
• "0" number after decimal separator (if I rewrite 0 character after decimal separator with some nonzero number in handicapped lines, it will display correctly)
• 3 digits after decimal separator (if I cut some number in decimal area and decrease decimal digits from 3 to 2, it will display correctly)

Is there some solution ideally trough native Excel? Thanks

Comment: Formatting the cells with 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000' doesn't work?

Comment: No, it doesn't, you can try. There's even problem already in format.

Comment: I must not have understand your problem.  That format makes those values appear exactly like you have them listed.  Excel 2010 tested.

Comment: I 'd tested in Excel 2003 and 2013, both the same result. There's an error, when I try to confirm this customize 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000'. It works only, if I delete '.000'. But then still lines 13, 20, 21 are incorrectly displayed. You try your customization on empty cells and then past my content?

Comment: By the way, my decimal separator is , not . but I guess there is no problem

Comment: @user2961195 I, too, cannot reproduce your problem in Excel 2007. Pasting the data from your message and formatting the cells results in a display the same as you show above.  Is the data that you paste showing the dot as the decimal separator, or have you changed it for this forum?

Comment: @user2961195 If your original data is showing dots as you show above, and your computer settings have comma as the decimal separator, then you need to replace the dots with the comma (either before or after you paste the data), else the date-time stamps will be treated as strings.

Comment: @1st data came from SQL, originally with dot, I do not change anything. Its really raw input with <cr><lf> end of lines.

Comment: @2nd I tryed both of them (dots and comma), even before paste and after paste, nothing doesn't work.

Comment: I got it! Theres settings in Windows Control panels to change decimal separator, another settings directly in (and only for) Excel, which overchange main settings in Windows. Both of them I got , BUT it also DEPENDS on your actual language environment (which I got on US, who use dot like decimal separator).